# Facebook new id not working in app(Getting null response)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, angularjs

Hi I have implemented a website in angularjs.

I have taken a new id from facebook,but the problem is I am getting null response from facebook when I am trying to connect via facebook in my site.

the code is below:-

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : '1412261982372017',   
            channelUrl : '//ABC.com/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });


    };

    (function(d, debug){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/ false));

</script>
```

Now the above code was working perfectly when i was using old id..But ever since I changed the id (Thrice now)I am not able to connect to facebook.

Please help me with this.

Comment: well it takes some time for Facebook  to update new ID of your FB app on all the FB servers, this is given in a note FB developers site, may be you need to try it after some time .

Comment: @dreamweiver I had changed the id for the second time and didn't work even after a day or two.BTW how much time does it take to update the app settings.

Comment: Typically depends on the locality, but should be up and running in a hour max.i`m not sure if you have morphed the App ID in your question here but a typical FB app ID is longer than that

Comment: Sometimes even the SDK might be old, just try updating that as well

Comment: @dreamweiver No I have not morphed in any way..The other id I am using is also of the same length.

Comment: @dreamweiver Then How was it working on the older id..I mean I just changed it a week back